# Catching and rethrowing an exception from a boolean method does return false whereas not doing anything causes the method not to return

Tags: java, exception

I have a general query regarding the java programming language and how it deals with exceptions and methods returning boolean.

Please not that although the example below deals with Spring/Ldap/ActiveDirectory, my question is only about **java** and **exceptions**.

```
public boolean doAuthenticate(String userAndDomain, String password) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(replaceBackSlashWithAtSign(userAndDomain), password);
        try {
            Authentication authentication = adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(userToken);
            return authentication.isAuthenticated();
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            log.error("Authentication failed - wrong username\\password", e);
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed - wrong username\\password", e);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            log.error("Authentication failed - AuthenticationException", e);
            throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication failed - AuthenticationException", e) { };
        }
    }
```

If any of `BadCredentialsException` or `AuthenticationException` is rethrown by the authenticate method, then the doAuthenticate method **returns false**.

**However** if for some reason **another runtime exception is thrown** by `adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()`, then the method does not return false and **does not return at all**...

I am just curious to know why that is...

**edit**:

```
 LdapAuthentifier authentifier = new LdapAuthentifierImpl();
 boolean didAuthenticate = authentifier.doAuthenticate(VALID_USER, INVALID_PASSWORD);
```

A `System.out.println` of `didAuthenticate` **does show false** if one of the two specified exceptions are thrown whereas another exception halts execution of the program and the `System.out.println` is never reached...

**edit 2**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 LdapAuthentifier authentifier = new LdapAuthentifierImpl();
 boolean didAuthenticate = authentifier.doAuthenticate(VALID_USER, INVALID_PASSWORD);
}
```

Comment: If you're rethrowing an exception, the method doesn't *return* any value... it throws an exception. It strikes me that you should tell us how you're calling the method, and in what way you think it returns `false` when rethrowing an exception...

Comment: Hello Jon and thanks for your input. I have included the client code as an edit.

Comment: Where do you handle those thrown exceptions? Please show us more of the code surrounding the code you added to your question in your edit.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention the client code is in a java main. I have added a second edit.

Comment: And what makes you think it returns `false`? That code will just terminate `main` with the same exception that you've rethrown...

Comment: Could you include the `println` statements you're talking about. Also; its not nessissary to say "edit:", just include the information as a single question. As if you wrote it like that to begin with

Comment: @Richard, Jon, and Forgivenson Bear with me and let me put together a simple sample that I will include here...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: your comment is unconstructive and I have flagged it as such. FYI, people posting here are here to learn and exchange...

Comment: In which way is unconstructive? Your current example doesn't show your point, and I'm asking for a proper example. Besides, as Jon already pointed out, the method won't return nor `true` nor `false`, it will throw an exception and the program will jump until the next catch block statement or until the `main` method, with means the exit of the application. And this question as-is defies this well-known behavior by no real proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what happened. Here is the explanation.

The exception I actually saw in the logs was `BadCredentialsException` but this exception **is never thrown** by `adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate` and **therefore never rethrown by the below method**.

What actually happened was that the `authentication.isAuthenticated()` was just returning false and I was passing this boolean value to the client code.

I am including the method again for clarity's sake:

```
 @Override
    public boolean doAuthenticate(String userAndDomain, String password) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(replaceBackSlashWithAtSign(userAndDomain), password);
        try {
            Authentication authentication = adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(userToken);
            return authentication.isAuthenticated();
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            log.error("Authentication failed - wrong username\\password", e);
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed - wrong username\\password", e);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            log.error("Authentication failed - AuthenticationException", e);
            throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication failed - AuthenticationException", e) { };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Had a feeling it would be something like this. Thanks for getting back to us